# Using an existing Q_PROPERTY to animate QGraphicsItem inheriting QObject

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qt5, qproperty

I have 2 classes, one MainWindow in which we draw in a QGraphicsView a circle (which intend to become a button !) created thanks to an other class.
The class MyCircle inherits from QObject and QGraphicsItem since I want to make animation.

My issue is the following :

My goal is first to make a simple animation on my drawing : make it smaller then it goes back to the original size. So I suppose I should use the property geometry, already existing in the QObject class.

To do this I write in my MainWindow.ccp

```
animationBoutonRondTaille = new QPropertyAnimation(roundButton, "geometry");
animationBoutonRondTaille->setDuration(1000);
animationBoutonRondTaille->setKeyValueAt(0, QRect(-100, -100, 200, 200));
animationBoutonRondTaille->setKeyValueAt(0.5, QRect(-80,-80,160,160));
animationBoutonRondTaille->setKeyValueAt(1, QRect(-100, -100, 200, 200));
animationBoutonRondTaille -> start();
```

If I don't include

```
class MyCircle : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QRect geometry READ geometry WRITE setGeometry)
/.../
}
```

I got the following error message :

```
QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property geometry of your QObject
```

But if I do, i got this one :

```
'class MyCircle' has no member named 'geometry'/'setgeometry'
```

What is the purpose of inheriting QObject if I have to define all by myself the geometry property ?

Hope you can help me, and sorry if my question is vague, it's the first for me so I don't really know what you expect.

Thanks a lot if you take time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the `geometry` and `setGeometry` methods, the `Q_PROPERTY` are used to call functions using the `setProperty("geometry", some_value)` and `property("geometry")` functions that are used internally in `QPropertyAnimation`, as well as in the Setter function (in this case `setGeometry`) you must call `update()` to update the graph.

**mycircle.h**

```
#ifndef MYCIRCLE_H
#define MYCIRCLE_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>

class MyCircle : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QRect geometry READ geometry WRITE setGeometry)
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
    explicit MyCircle(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QRect geometry() const;
    void setGeometry(const QRect &value);

    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget);

private:

    QRect rect;
};

#endif // MYCIRCLE_H
```

**mycircle.cpp**

```
#include "mycircle.h"

MyCircle::MyCircle(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    rect = QRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
}

QRect MyCircle::geometry() const
{
    return rect;
}

void MyCircle::setGeometry(const QRect &value)
{
    if(rect!=value){
        rect = value;
        update();
    }
}

QRectF MyCircle::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(rect);
}


void MyCircle::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
           QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option)
    Q_UNUSED(widget)
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
    painter->drawEllipse(rect);
}
```

A complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/CircleItem)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `QObject` does not have a `geometry` property. It is a property of `QWidget`. The error message is telling you that there are no `geometry` and `setGeometry` member functions. So you have to provide those methods. See [the example in property system docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#a-simple-example).

Comment: My mistake in deed ! Thanks for your answer.